# Generating spatially uncorrelated random fields in R

Tags: r, spatial

I have a DEM (cellsize 10x10 and cells.dim 450x300)
and I need to create 100 random error grids 
that have the same dimensions as the DEM.

The values in the error grids are generated from a 
normal distribution that has mean of zero and
a standard deviation equal to the RMSE of original DEM ~ (0, +-3).

Then I need to add those error grids to the original DEM 
and create 100 realisation of the original DEM.

Comment: I think this really belongs on SO where it was originally asked.  `replicate`, `matrix`, `rnorm` should be all that are needed to do this ...

Comment: @Ben I believe Cross Validated is as good a place as any for this question, because its error model is unrealistic: the OP may benefit from comments and replies that show how to construct (far) better error models for DEMs.

Comment: @whuber: fair enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the first part of this in R rather easily:

```
 errmats <- replicate(100,
     matrix(rnorm(450*300,mean=0,sd=3),nrow=450),simplify=FALSE)
```

gives a list of 100 450-by-300 matrices with uncorrelated random errors as specified. (If you omit the `simplify=FALSE`, you'll instead get the results stored as a 450-by-300-by-100 array.) Since you didn't tell us how your DEMs (digital elevation models) are stored/structured within R, it's a little hard to say exactly how to add them to your original DEM.

A comment above suggests that your error model is unrealistic: I can't say, since I don't know what you're trying to do (not enough context). However, should you choose to use more realistic (spatially correlated) error structures you can easily generate them using the `RandomFields` package.

Comment: DEM is data.frame object ('SpatialGridDataFrame'). I'm trying something that I read in paper 'The eﬀect of error in gridded digital elevation models on the estimation of topographic parameters':). I want to determine the aﬀect of DEM errors on slope. DEM uncertainty is given with a single rms error

Comment: "A simple Monte Carlo simulation of DEM error
simulates values for each grid cell independent of the
rest of the surface. The error simulation process begins
with the generation of random error grids that have the
same dimensions as the original DEM. The values in the
error grids are generated from a normal probability
distribution that has a standard deviation (stdv) equal to
the rms error of original DEM and a mean of zero. The
error grids are then added to the original DEM, creating
a realisation of the original DEM."

Comment: Martin, this is a terrible model: DEM errors do not behave this way. They have very long-range spatial correlations. If this were not the case, DEMs would have a salt-and-pepper look to them, which they don't. I won't deny that plenty of people may have published peer-reviewed papers using such a model, but it's still wrong and not defensible for use in any realistic study. If you truly want to understand how DEM errors affect slope, then you must (1) use a reasonably correlated error model and (2) account for positional error. For more about this, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/1573.

Comment: you're right! I guess I first need to understand DEMs and errors and then start messing with the data :)

Comment: Martin, you might want to read the paper _Error propagation of DEM-based surface derivatives_ (Computers & Geosciences, v31 n8) where the authors use autocorrelation models to represent the correlation structure of DEM errors.